# how to control class on ajax response text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am returning some data from the ajax call and based on that , i display the button class to visible or hidden...

but what should i do, when I want to keep the visibility hidden for some case of reponses like below

```
<div class="ui positive right labeled icon button" style="display:none;" id="add_wholesaler_button">
  Add Wholesaler
  <i class="checkmark icon"></i>
</div>
```

## javascript

```
var code = $('#search_wholesaler').val();
if (code == "" || code.length < 1) {

  add_wholesaler_button.style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('nameWhole').innerHTML = "";
  return false;
} else {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
      add_wholesaler_button.style.display = 'inline';
      document.getElementById('nameWhole').innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
    }

  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "getWholesaler" + '/' + code, true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

now what should I do that when I receive the response like "NO ID EXISTS" , I wanted to revert back the display visibilty to hidden?

any help to this is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

if i understand it correct you want to hide an element if the ajax response is equal to "NO ID EXISTS"
You could add this code inside your ajax

```
if (xhttp.responseText == 'NO ID EXISTS') {
    add_wholesaler_button.style.display = 'none';
}
```

Is this what you needed?

Comment: i already did that...but ajax does not throw any error...instead it responds as that if statement does not exists only

Comment: so your ajax doesnt return 'NO ID EXISTS' if there is no id, but what does it return? could you do a console.log(xhttp.responseText) and place te respone?

Comment: it responds me NO ID EXISTS only... have you tried an ajax code with an If statetmet like u provided?

Comment: Yes i did, could you put your code online anywhere?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1SqS3Ujajkl9AMSMw3nGzvlswFtAIZAh-BTUCez_QyJk/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

```
if (xhttp.responseText == 'NO ID EXISTS') {
    add_wholesaler_button.style.display = 'none';
}
```

it should work,you can see this demo:http://www.developerbooks.club